# Software for running dynamics simulation of polymeric and mixed biomaterial (e.g hydrogels)

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, molecular-dynamics

I was working on the development of a soft solid hydrogel having polymeric chains and molecules of different compounds dissolved in Phosphate Buffered Saline solution. There is a sub-study regarding the interaction of two samples of the same hydrogel placed in contact with each other.

I want to study the changes in this interaction behaviour upon changing the ratios of constituent compounds in the hydrogel through dynamics simulations.

Can anyone please suggest the best or appropriate software or softwares for this purpose? (Several aspects or combinations can be considered including high precision and accuracy, visual simulations, ease of use, molecular and material dynamics, etc.)